# Python string letter substitution using zip()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was going through some Python challenges and this particular one has been bugging my mind and thought it would be worth getting some explaining. It reads:

> Have the function LetterChanges(str) take the str parameter being passed and modify it using the following algorithm. Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a). Then capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and finally return this modified string.

Example:

```
Input: "fun times!"
Output: gvO Ujnft!
```

The code:

```
def LetterChanges(str):
  letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW"
  changes = "bcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZ"
  mapping = { k:v for (k,v) in zip(str+letters,str+changes) }
  return "".join([ mapping[c] for c in str ])
```

I understand that it takes two strings, letters and changes. It uses the zip() function that takes iterators and 'zips' them, forming an iterator in the form of a dictionary. `k:v for (k,v)` It's a dict comprehension.

My doubts are:

What exactly is happening with `str+letters,str+changes` and why it had to be done?

`[ mapping[c] for c in str ]` Why is it that by doing this, we accomplish the replacement of every key with its value or has it says in the challenge description: "Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet"

Comment: Note, `{k:v for k,v in whatever}` is a verbose way of writing `dict(whatever)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line:

```
mapping = { k:v for (k,v) in zip(str+letters,str+changes) }
```

As you already observed, creates a dictionary using dictionary comprehension syntax. The resulting dictionary will associate each letter with the "new" letter to be used when translating the string. Usually, it would be done like this:

```
mapping = {k: v for k, v in zip(source, destination)}
```

Or even shorter:

```
mapping = dict(zip(source, destination))
```

However, the next line does the following:

```
"".join([ mapping[c] for c in str ])
```

It blindly transforms every single character in `str` doing a lookup in the dictionary that was just created. If the string contains any character that is not in the mapping, this fails.

To get around this issue, whoever wrote the above code used the silly trick of first adding every single character of the string to the map, associating it with itself, and then adding the corresponding mapping for characters to be replaced.

So here:

```
mapping = { k:v for (k,v) in zip(str+letters,str+changes) }
```

The `str+` before `letters` and before `changes` prepends the whole content of the string to both the originals and the replacements, creating a mapping for each character of the string that is not in `letters`.

This is the same as:

```
mapping = {k: k for k in str}
mapping.update({k: v for k, v in zip(letters, changes)})
```

Which is anyway both awful and slow, so to answer your question:

> why it had to be done?

Because whoever wrote the code decided to. There's no need for it, it takes `O(len(str))` time to build the mapping, going through the whole string, when there really is no need to. No Python programmer would have wrote it that way.

The 'good' way of doing it would have been:

```
mapping = dict(zip(source, destination))
return ''.join(mapping.get(c, c) for c in str)
```

---

All in all, the above code is pretty awkward and IMHO accomplishes the task in a very messy way.

Easy to spot problems are:

1. The mapping iterates over the whole string, which is totally unneeded.
2. A mapping is created to replace characters, but does not take advantage of the already existing [`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) built-in methods available in Python.
3. The letters `X`, `Y`, `Z` are missing from the `letters` string, and therefore not transformed.
4. The list comprehension inside `join` is totally unneeded, it could be done without the square brackets `[]`.
5. The variable name `str` overrides the global type name `str`, which is bad and should not be done.

A better solution would be:

```
def LetterChanges(s):
    old = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    new = 'bcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvwxyzAZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY'
    table = str.maketrans(old, new)
    return s.translate(table)
```

Even better would be to pre-calculate the table only one time and then use the already created one on successive calls:

```
def LetterChanges(s, table={}):
    if not table:
        old = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
        new = 'bcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvwxyzAZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY'
        table.update(str.maketrans(old, new))

    return s.translate(table)
```

Performance:

- Original: 1.081s for 100k translations of `Hello World!`.
- Updated: 0.400s for 100k translations of `Hello World!` (4.5x speedup).
- Updated with caching: 0.082s for 100k translations of `Hello World!` (22.5x speedup).

Answer (score 2):

> What exactly is happening with `str+letters,str+changes` and why it had to be done?

Because the input string `"fun times!"` doesn't just contain letters from the alphabet; it also contains a space `' '` and an exclamation mark `'!'`. If these aren't keys in the dictionary `mapping`, then `mapping[c]` will raise a `KeyError` when `c` is one of those characters.

So the purpose of `zip(str + letters, str + changes)` is to ensure that every character present in the string is mapped to itself in the dictionary, before adding the actually-required transformations into the dictionary. Note that because it's `str + ...` with `str` first, any letters of the alphabet in `str` will map to themselves first, and *then* be overwritten by the mapping from `letters` to `changes`.

That said, it would be simpler to use `mapping.get` instead of `mapping[...]`, since the `get` method allows a default to be returned in case the key is not present. In that case, we don't have to make sure every character in the input string is present as a key in the dictionary.

```py
def letter_changes(string):
    letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW"
    changes = "bcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZ"
    mapping = { k: v for (k, v) in zip(letters, changes) }
    return "".join(mapping.get(c, c) for c in string)
```

Here `mapping.get(c, c)` means, *"get the mapping associated with the key `c`, or if `c` is not a key in the dictionary, just use `c` itself"*. This means a symbol like `' '` or `'!'` which is not in the dictionary will be left unchanged.